# fully qualified domain name requirement incompatible w/ specific repo gh-pages

Tags: hosting, github-pages

I know that it's easy to create a link between gh-pages for a GitHub account, such as enezhadian.github.io, but for a subdomain, i.e. a project in a specific repository, how can we do it?

When I try to add the following:

`http://enezhadian.github.io/Swopular/`

as a `CNAME Record` on NameCheap I get this error message:

```
CNAME record is invalid: Address is invalid. 
The address (enezhadian.github.io/swopular/) 
must be a defined host name or fully qualified 
domain name.
```

as I said, this problem is the result of using the `/Swopular/` component of the URL, but it's indispensable! How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`enezhadian.github.io` is your user/organization repository.

You want to reach something at https://enezhadian.github.io/Swopular/

This is not what you call a **subdomain**. This is just your repository at `https://github.com/enezhadian/Swopular` but if you want to reach it, you first have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

CNAME (canonical name) record maps a domain or sub-domain to another address or hostname. It cannot map the sub-directories separated by the "/". Following a basic CNAME record syntax.

Source domain/subdomain.......CNAME........Destination domain/subdomain

In your case, first you'll have to create sub-domain "swopular.enezhadian.github.io" and then try adding a CNAME record.